# React : How can I populate the data that is saved in the local storage?

Tags: reactjs

I want to prefill the values with the values in localstorage on loading the page. How can I populate the data on the page. The data is appearing in the console but it is not showing the data on the screen. Even I want to edit the form after prefilling the data. I am trying to figure it out but don't know where I am going wrong. How can I achieve this?

### Here's the code :

```
class MileStoneForm extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
                deliverable_name:"",
                due_date:"",
                deliverable_notes:"",
                milestone_based_payment:false,
                deliverable_name_error:"",
                due_date_error:"",
                deliverable_notes_error:"",
                percent_rate:0,
                percent_rate_error:"",
                edit:false,
                milestonedata:null
        }
    }
    
    componentDidMount(){
        let milestonedata=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('mileStoneData'))
        console.log(milestonedata)
        if(this.state.edit===true){
            this.setState({
                deliverable_name:milestonedata.milestoneName,
                deliverable_notes:milestonedata.description,
                due_date:milestonedata.dueDate,
                milestone_based_payment:milestonedata.isMilestoneBasedPayment,
                percent_rate:milestonedata.percentageRate
            })
        }
    }
    render() {
        const {deliverable_name,deliverable_name_error,deliverable_notes,deliverable_notes_error,
            due_date,due_date_error,milestone_based_payment,}=this.state
        return (
            <>
                <div className="milestone">
                    <div className="milestone-header">ADD MILESTONE</div>
                    <Grid container className="milestone-deliverable-name-date">
                        <Grid item md={6} lg={6} xs={12}>
                            <div className="milestone-deliverable-name">DELIVERABLE NAME</div>
                                
                                    <InputBase
                                    className={`milestone-input-deliverable-name`}
                                    autoComplete={"off"}
                                    placeholder={"MileStone Name"}
                                    onChange={e=>this.handleChange(e,'deliverable_name')}
                                    value={deliverable_name}
                                    maxLength="100"
                                    autoFocus={true}/>
                                    {deliverable_name_error && (
                                        <div className="input-error-style">{deliverable_name_error}</div>
                                    )}
                                
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item md={6} lg={6} xs={12}>
                                        <div className="milestone-due-date">
                                            DUE DATE
                                        </div>
                                        <label>
                                                <DatePicker
                                                dateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy"
                                                margin="normal"
                                                selected={due_date}
                                                placeholderText="Due Date"
                                                onChange={date=>this.handleChangeDate(date,'due_date')}
                                                maxDate={new Date()}
                                                className={`milestone-input-due-date`}
                                                />
                                                <img src={DROP_D} alt="drop down" style={{cursor:'pointer'}} className='dropdown-milestone'/>                                                        
                                        </label>

                                    {due_date_error && (
                                        <div className="input-error-style">{due_date_error}</div>
                                    )}
                        </Grid>
                    
                        <Grid item md={12} lg={12} xs={12}>
                            <div className="milestone-notes-description">
                                <div className="milestone-deliverable-notes">DELIVERABLE NOTES</div>
                                <div className="milestone-description-notes">Add description below</div>
                                <TextareaAutosize className={`milestone-textarea-description`}
                                onChange={(e)=>this.handleChange(e,'deliverable_notes')}
                                value={deliverable_notes}/>
                                {deliverable_notes_error && (
                                    <div className="input-error-style">{deliverable_notes_error}</div>
                                )}
                            </div>
                        </Grid>
                    
                    
                        <Grid item md={12} lg={12} xs={12}>
                                <div className="milestone-payment">MILESTONE BASED PAYMENT?</div>
                                {this.togglePayment()}
                        </Grid>

                        <Grid item md={12} lg={12} xs={12}>
                            {milestone_based_payment ?<>
                                <div className="percent-rate">PERCENT RATE</div>
                                    <InputBase
                                    className={`milestone-percent-rate`}
                                    autoComplete={"off"}
                                    placeholder={"20%"}
                                    maxLength="100"
                                    value={this.state.percent_rate}
                                    onChange={(e)=>{this.handleChange(e, "percent_rate")}}
                                    />
                                    {
                                        this.state.percent_rate_error && (
                                        <div className="input-error-style">{this.state.percent_rate_error}</div>
                                        )
                                    }
                                    </> :''}
                        </Grid>
                    
                    
                            <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={4} lg={4}></Grid>
                            <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={4} lg={4}></Grid>
                            <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={4} lg={4}>
                                <div className={milestone_based_payment?"milestone-button":"milestone-button-margin-btm"}>
                                <NormalButton
                                buttonValue="ADD"
                                className="btn-create-project flex-justify"
                                icon_color="black"
                                handleButtonAction={()=>this.handleSubmit()}
                                />
                                </div>
                            </Grid>
                        
                        </Grid>
                    </div>
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default MileStoneForm
```

Comment: In the CDM - you have a condition `this.state.edit` which should be `true` to populate the data from the `localStorage`. Just put `edit` in the constructor to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `this.state.edit` is `false` by default in your state. I can't see anywhere in your code that you are changing to `true`. Because of that your local state does not get populated since you are checking `this.state.edit`.

```
if(this.state.edit===true){ // <= this line
  this.setState({
    deliverable_name:milestonedata.milestoneName,
    deliverable_notes:milestonedata.description,
    due_date:milestonedata.dueDate,      
    milestone_based_payment:milestonedata.isMilestoneBasedPayment,
    percent_rate:milestonedata.percentageRate
  })
}
```

For making it work you can either remove the `if-statement` or turn `this.state.edit` to `true` somewhere in your code. Or you can change its default value from `false` to `true`.

```
this.state={
  deliverable_name:"",
  due_date:"",
  deliverable_notes:"",
  milestone_based_payment:false,
  deliverable_name_error:"",
  due_date_error:"",
  deliverable_notes_error:"",
  percent_rate:0,
  percent_rate_error:"",
  edit: true, // <= here
  milestonedata:null
}
```